# Select some elements of a column and find the maximum of them,repeatedly over a large file. USING PYTHON

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large file with 2.2 million rows.

```
Value Label
4       1
6       1
2       2
6       2
3       2
5       3
8       3
7       3
1       4
5       4
2       5
4       5 
1       5
```

I want to know the fastest way to get following output, where 'Max' stores the maximum value in each label

```
Label   Max
  1      6
  2      6
  3      8
  4      5
  5      4
```

I implemented a normal logic using 'for'&'while' loops in python, but it takes hours. I expect pandas will have something for tackling this.

Comment: what is lakhs by the way?

Comment: @EdChum I [found it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lakh) - it's one hundred thousand

Comment: @PawelWisniewski sounds a useful counter I will add it my arsenal of obfuscated measuring units like stones, drams, man (10,000) etc..

Comment: @EdChum to confuse future generation I shall use it in my code comments and as variables names...

Comment: Lakhs, crores are commonly used in asian countries. They dont use million, billion as units.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Call `max` on a groupby object:

```
In [116]:

df.groupby('Label').max()
Out[116]:
       Value
Label       
1          6
2          6
3          8
4          5
5          4
```

If you want to restore the `Label` column from the index then call `reset_index`:

```
In [117]:

df.groupby('Label').max().reset_index()
Out[117]:
   Label  Value
0      1      6
1      2      6
2      3      8
3      4      5
4      5      4
```